# Why do git commit-msg on Windows not match regex

Tags: regex, bash, shell, git-bash

I am trying to create a git commit-msg hook, which includes a simple regex to verify the log message. It is not working using the usual bash syntax.

I tried it using a very simple regex, and it is still not working

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Here is a simple example including an obvious match, but it is printing out "no match"

```
#!/bin/bash
message="[GLSD-0000]"
echo "Message: '$message'"
regex="\[GLSD-\w+\]"
if [[ $message =~ $regex ]]; then echo "yes";else echo "no match!"; fi
```

Using git version 2.18.0.windows.1

Comment: Bash typically doesn't support Perl-style generic character types like `\w`. Read up on [POSIX extended regular expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) instead ( or consult `man re_format` if available on your local machine).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things to note from you attempt made,

1. Your interpreter does `#!/bin/sh` does not support the regex operation in `bash`, even-though you have not used it. You should be using the bourne again shell `bash` (`#!/usr/bin/env bash)`.
2. The `[[..]]` with an `=` does a string match on left side operand with the right side operand. For regular expression support, you need to use the `~` operator
3. The `bash` only supports a minimal version of ERE (Extended Regular expression) in which `\w` (all words) is not supported.

So in a script targeted for a `bash` shell, you should be writing it as

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# equivalent of '\w' in the regex flavor supported by bash
re='\[GLSD-[A-Za-z0-9_]+\]'
msg='[GLSD-0000]'
[[ $msg =~ $re ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no match!"
```

Comment: Also, `/bin/sh` doesn't support `[[ ]]` to begin with.

Comment: And shouldn't `1` probably be `$1`? `1` is always alphanumeric and the test wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminW. . I’ll leave it upto the OP to use it as they wish.

Comment: Sorry some transcription errors. Please see the corrected

Comment: @VictorGrazi: Updated to match your example